# Multiple permission to end user groups

Tags: php, mysql

I've created a database using MySQL with PHP as it's front end. And for end users I've created a username table and data excess level table, I've also created a table in which I've linked usernames with the products against which I wanted users to see their respective products only. It was executed flawlessly, but it only pick the first product of each user and leave the others.

I am thinking to create a separate table with the name of group in which I can link it with username and excess level table. But I am unable to think of a way to do this.

Any better idea to do this without any difficulties?

Table structure:

```
--------------------------------------------
| username    | product_user | excesslevel |
--------------------------------------------
| usernameid  | pu_id        | excessid    |
| username    | productname  | excesslevel |
| password    | username     | username    |
|-------------|--------------|-------------|
```

Comment: Can you provide the tables structures? It will be easier to understand how you implemented this and how to improve it.

Comment: username table
usernameid---username---password
product_user table
pu_id---productname---username
excesslevel
excessid---excesslevel---username

Comment: I've updated your question to add your database structure, please fix it if I made a mistake trying to understand it.

Comment: No it is okay. I am sorry, that I couldn't made that clear in first go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
------------------------------
| username    | product_user |
------------------------------
| userId      | pu_id        |
| username    | productname  |
| password    | userId       |
|-------------|--------------|
```

If I userstand this correctly... A user can only access their own products.

If that is true, query your database with:

```
SELECT * FROM product_user WHERE userId = 1
```

This would give you every products that belong to user 1. A third database would be required to assign a same product to different users.

Also, don't use the username in another table. If the username change, you'll need to update many rows from different tables. Assign it's ID instead.

Comment: I didn't change the username, I've linked product table with username table by it's ID.
Okay, I have to create another database if I wanted 1 user to see his products, but his boos to view all products of his units?